# Number of normal modes between two frequencies

Tags: waves, wavefunction

I am given a wave function and a cuboidal cavity, and I want to calculate the number of modes in that cavity between two frequencies $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1 > \omega_0$. I believe modes in this context means "standing waves", but I don't know how to calculate the number of modes between two frequencies. I know that Rayleigh-Jeans and similar laws exist, but those give me the number of modes of one frequency, so this problem has me stumped.

I'd like a nudge in the right direction so I have something to go off of. I don't want a solution to this problem, I just want a starting point on how to approach this.

If its needed, the wavefunction is $u_{\vec{k}}(t, \vec{x}) = e^{i(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{k} - \omega t)}$, so basically a sinusoidal wave, and the cavity is a cuboid with sidelengths 2$\pi$.

Comment: Are you sure about the wave function? You need to fulfill boundary conditions (i.e. amplitude is zero at the cavity walls) and this wave function can't do that.

Comment: If you have a matrix equation that describes the system and has the eigenvalues/vectors corresponding to the modes, you can use a Sturm sequence technique to find the number of modes with frequencies less than a specified $\omega$. So do that twice to get the number of frequencies in a range. The basic idea of a Sturm sequence is that you factorize the matrix and count the number of negative diagonal terms as you do it.

Comment: Anyway, this system seems to be called "rectangular cavity resonator" and you can find the complete derivation [here](http://wcchew.ece.illinois.edu/chew/ece350/ee350-23.pdf).  To count the actual number of resonances within a frequency range, you need to vary n, m and p and... count.